# Removing eshell automatic correction

Tags: eshell

This question is surprisingly difficult for me to formulate in a google-able way, but how can I stop eshell from correcting away my asterisks? For example, if I try

```
$ rm ./*~
```

to remove auto-saved files in current working directory, eshell removes the statement when I type *, and with some lag, in fact, leaving me with this statement (visible just too late for me to stop myself from executing)

```
$ rm ~
```

which is fortunately not as dangerous as it appears. But still, this seems like an accident waiting to happen, so what is exactly happening here, and how can I get it to go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not Eshell, but `company-mode` (maybe `autocomplete-mode` as well, I'm not sure). Try turning `company-mode` off and see if entering an asterisk (`*`) still has the same behavior.

This issue is [#128](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/218) for `company-mode` on GitHub.

As a workaround, you can enter an asterisk with `quoted-insert` (<kbd>C-q</kbd> by default).